# A formal local triviality statement for smooth maps

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a smooth morphism of schemes of finite type over a field $k$, and suppose that $f(p) = q$.  Let $Z = f^{-1}(q)$ be the fiber of $f$.  Let $\hat{X}$ be the formal completion of $X$ at $p$, $\hat{Y}$ the formal completion of $Y$ at $q$, and $\hat{Z}$ the formal completion of $Z$ at $p$.

Does $f$ induce an isomorphism $\hat{X}\cong \hat{Y}\times\hat{Z}$ of formal schemes?

This seems like it must be both true and well-known, but I can't find a reference!

Comment: EGA IV 17.11.4 provides an étale map $X\rightarrow Y\times \mathbb{A}^n$. From this you get immediately  isomorphisms $\hat{X}\cong \hat{Y}\times \hat{\mathbb{A}}^n$ and $\hat{Z}\cong \hat{\mathbb{A}}^n$.